# Kotlin - <T> versus <T : Any>

Tags: kotlin

There are some cases in Kotlin where the compiler will complain about a generic type parameter defined as `<T>` and expects `<T : Any>`. What is the difference?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The difference is that a plain `<T>` means that it can be `null`able. (which is represented by `Any?`). Using `<T: Any>` will restrict `T` to non-nullable types.

So the difference is that `<T>` is an implicit `<T: Any?>`.

Comment: I am just curious about the `T` being implicitly `Nullable`. 

doesn't Null also extend `Any` class?

Comment: `null` doesn't extend anything. It is just the only possible value for `Any?`. When you type `T` it is equal to typing `T: Any?`. Kotlin just lets you spare some key presses.

Comment: thanks. I couldn't find the reference to this anywhere. So, I always thought it will be the same as `Object` in `Java`

Comment: No, because Kotlin supports nullable types. I think that's where the confusion comes from.

Comment: But in Kotlin, if not specified, isn't everything non nullable by default??

Comment: It _is_ the same as `Object` because `Object` corresponds to `Any?` and not to `Any`. It is not true that, as opposed to Java, "Kotlin supports nullable types". What it supports are _non-nullable_ types.

Comment: I would also add that it is not correct to say that `<T>` means it is nullable. It means that it may be either nullable or non-nullable.

Comment: Effectively, `<T>` is the same as `<T : Any?>`.  `Any` is a non-nullable subtype of the nullable type `Any?`, and `<T : Any>` restricts `T` to non-nullable types.  Depending on the context, both `Any` and `Any?` can map to `java.lang.Object`; Kotlin's type system is finer-grained than Java's.

Comment: @gidds That's what I said (or at least tried to say).

Comment: @AdamArold so why do we even have both of them (any and T) if they do the same thing. Could't we just use Any? insted of T...

Comment: @Kratos it is a shorthand, and I think they did it this way for Java compatibility reasons.

Comment: @AdamArold aha yeas that makes sense. Thanks for answer!